# Cutting segments from convex objects

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $X$ be some convex object in the plane. For every pair of points $A,B$ that are *not* in $X$, and the distance between them is at most $1$, we remove from $X$ its intersection with the segment $AB$. For example, in the picture below, $X$ is the green circle, and if the distance between $A$ and $B$ is at most $1$, then the entire black segment is removed from $X$:

[image]

Note that we first find all A,B with distance at most $1$ and define the to-be-removed segments, and then remove them all at once.
Denote the new object (after the removals) by $Y$.

I am trying to understand how $Y$ looks like.

If $X$ is a disc (with diameter larger than $1$), then it is easy to see that $Y$ is a disc too: it has the same center as $X$ and a smaller radius.

MY QUESTION: if $X$ is an arbitrary convex object, is $Y$ convex too?

Comment: Is this distinct from the following? "For a given convex object $C$, let $S$ denote the set of all chords of $C$ with length $1$. Find the envelope of all elements of $S$." I think this reformulation works, as long as $C$ is convex, and (for me at least) it's a bit easier to work with.

Comment: Assuming you don't cut away slice by slice (you would end up with the empty set) but first find all all such $A, B$ and define the to-be-removed segment, and then remove them all at once, the result would be convex.  It's basically an intersection of convex shapes (the cutting away of a segment is just the intersection with the corresponding half-plane).

Comment: @fweth is right - intersecting convex regions means $D$ will be convex. Are you interested in the actual shape of $D$ too?

Comment: Note that it's not clear to me how you decide which side of the line you cut away, e.g. if the line cuts the shape in half.  But basically you can take any set of half-planes and intersect them, whatever the process of describing the set.

Comment: Good point - my reformulation falls apart when the shape is too small. But I suppose those shapes are entirely cut away?

Comment: @fweth: what I meant is to cut only the segment itself (not the entire half-plane on one side of it). When $C$ is a circle, and you cut such segments, you still end up cutting an entire "envelope" of $C$. But I don't know how to prove this for general convex sets.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand.  After the cut, you want something like the gray shape here to remain?  https://i.imgur.com/1E1g69k.png

Comment: @fweth. After the cut of a single segment, the remainder is only $C$ minus that segment (the green region in my picture). Of course, if you cut many segments, you will end up with something like in your picture.

Comment: But the green region is the whole circle?  You only want to remove the line segment itself, so you end up with a disconnected subset of the disk?

Comment: @fweth the green region is the whole circle minus the black segment. Indeed, it is disconnected (but after removing many segments, it becomes connected again).

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean.  Once you removed such a segment (and split the region in two), there will be one half of which you can remove any point using a segment parallel to your first one (and same length).  Hence you can describe the process of removing the segments equivalently as intersections with half-planes.  Should I write down the proof for this?

Comment: Ah sorry, there is some subtetly still going on with non-open sets.  I didn't realize that e.g. the open square with a single point added from its border is still convex.  Are you interested in open regions only or also ones neither open nor closed?

Comment: @fweth For my application, it is sufficient to handle only closed sets.

Comment: @ChrisLewis your alternative reformulation is interesting - I am looking for simpler ways to describe the process. Can you elaborate - what do you mean by the "envelope" of the chords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll consider closed sets only, as you mentioned in your comment.  Please let us denote regions with $X,Y,Z,\dots$ and reserve $A,B,C,\dots$ for points, especially let $X$ be the total region.  If $[A,B]$ is a segment as described in your question, we can assume w.l.o.g. that removing it dissects $X$ into two parts $Y,Z$ (the other case is easy).  My claim is that after removing all segments of your kind, either $Y$ or $Z$ vanishes.  Assume not, then you have points $y\in Y,z\in Z$ which are not part of any such segment.  In particular you can choose segments $[C,D]\subseteq Y$ containing $y$ and $[E,F]\subseteq Z$ containing $z$, both of length $1$ and paralell to $[A,B]$.  Since $X$ is convex and $C,D,E,F\in X$, the segments $[C,E]$ and $[D,F]$ must be fully contained in $X$ as well.  But also at least one of those segments must intersect with the line through $A,B$ outside of $(A,B):=[A,B]\setminus\{A,B\}$, a contradiction, as no such point is contained in $X$.

Hence for each line segment $[A,B]$ you remove, there is a set of line segments whose removal includes all points to the left or all points to the right of $[A,B]$.  So removing all your line segments is equivalent to intersecting with a set of open half-planes, which yields a convex set.  It can also be checked that the set is closed.

Comment: I do not understand why "at least one of those segments must intersect with the line through $A,B$ outside of $(A,B)$". See this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrlgk.png where both [C,E] and [D,F] intersect with $(A,B)$.

Comment: Maybe you meant: "you can choose segments [C,D]⊆Y containing y and [E,F]⊆Z containing z, both paralell to [A,B], **such that their length is larger than 1.**"?

Comment: Ah yes, will do an edit!

Comment: Length $1$ will do, I think.

Comment: Thanks! Based on your proof, is there a simpler way to describe the entire process of removal? I thought of "remove from $X$ the entire halfplane at one side of the line through $AB$", but it is not clear how to define that "one side".

Comment: I'd describe it this way.  For every angle $\alpha$, you can measure the diameter of $X$ along every line at angle $\alpha$.  This gives you a map $\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ which is non-decreasing up to a point and then non-increasing.  If it gets above $1$, slice away the two open half-planes made up from lines at angle $\alpha$ along which the diameter is less than $1$.  Repeat for all angles $\alpha$.